# FCM/IOS, how to know if an user tapped on a notification alert or if we receive the notification directly?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

on ios 9 and below, when **an user click on a notification alert**, it's fire the event `applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification` but **when the app is in foreground** the notification arrive straight away to the app without showing any alert to the end user, and the event `applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification` is also called :(

so how to know if the user click on a notification alert (maybe an old one) or if we receive the notification straight away because the app was in foreground ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the application states like this.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
    // Just received notification (Foreground)
} else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    // launched by taping notification
} else if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateBackground) {
    // Just received notification (Background)
}
```

Comment: no it's not work at all, applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification is also call when when launch the app and their is pending data message in the queue

Comment: Yes 'applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification' is always called but you can check application state to determine if the notification is clicked or received. I hope I understand your question right.

Comment: 'applicationDidReceiveRemoteNotification' Can you post your code of the function?

Comment: it's ok finally, just looking is the node "aps" is present ot not :)